# Integral of modified Bessel function is wrong

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

A simple integration of a modified Bessel function gives:

```
In[106]:= tt[yIn_]:=(9 Sqrt[3]/8 Pi) Integrate[BesselK[5/3,yi],{yi,yIn,Infinity},Assumptions->{yi>0,yIn>0}]
In[109]:= tt[100.0]
Out[109]= -6.430605433593966*10^27
```

The result should be small and positive as shown if I use NIntegrate:

```
In[110]:= (9 Sqrt[3]/8 Pi) NIntegrate[BesselK[5/3, yi], {yi, 100.0, Infinity}]
Out[110]= 2.875666186745843*10^-44
```

How can I get the Integrate value to behave as I would expect like NIntegrate?

Comment: you use a very rough number 100.0, check 100.0`100. you will get the same result 4.69759*10^-45

Comment: Multiply by constant `(9 Sqrt[3]/8 Pi)` of course

Comment: I tried converting your integral to a Meijer $G$ representation, but even that was numerically unstable to evaluate. Interesting...

Answer (score 4):

You can actually solve your integral symbolically:

```
Block[{yIn},
 (tt[yIn_] := (9 Sqrt[3]/8 Pi)*#) &[
  Integrate[BesselK[5/3, yi], {yi, yIn, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> yIn > 0]
  ]
 ]
```

and `tt[100]` gives an expression with special functions that seem to be problematic numerically

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, now you can simply do

```
tt[100`100]

(* 2.875666186580*10^-44 + 0.*10^-73 I *)
```

So the problem is not `Integrate` but the numerical evaluation of the result.